# Is there a Neo4j maven repository for old dependencies?

Tags: java, neo4j

I have an old project which uses spring data and neo4j. I'm trying to build it, but maven is not able to find the `neo4j-cypher-dsl` dependency. The dependency is defined as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

These are the repositories that I have configured in pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j</id>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j-releases</id>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And this is the error that I'm getting from maven:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project evidencefactory: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.evidencefactory:evidencefactory:war:0.9-SNAPSHOT: Failed to
>   collect dependencies at
>   org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE ->
>   org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE ->
>   org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:pom:2.0.1 from/to neo4j
>   (http://m2.neo4j.org/): **Failed to transfer file
>   http://m2.neo4j.org/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-dsl-2.0.1.pom
>   with status code 502 -> [Help 1]**

Does anyone know where I can find this old neo4j dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating my answer to use another repo.
See my comment below for the location of the artifacts.
Adding this to my pom.xml builds this dependency.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>xebialabs-releases</id>          
      <url>https://plugins.xebialabs.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the mvnrepository site and found the link you point on the search. The artifact page (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1) has a note at the bottom "this artifact it located at Spring Plugins repository (repo.spring.io/plugins-release)", but the Spring Plugins repository does not contain it. Also, the repository defined in the Baeldung site (http://repo.spring.io/release) does not contain the artifact as well.

Comment: I see it is availalble from https://plugins.xebialabs.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1/
The settings for repo are here https://docs.xebialabs.com/v.9.5/xl-deploy/how-to/configure-xl-deploy-to-fetch-artifacts-from-a-maven-repository/#step-2---configure-xl-deploy-maven-repositories
I was able to make it work but it is not seamless. I was getting an auth error, but the url above doesn't have any authentication. After some tries i was able to get the artifacts to download and build.

Comment: updated my answer. you can update your pom.xml wtih new repo settings see if it works for you.